# Errorbars in r of two groups ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot standard deviations of the `mean(z)/mean(b)` which are grouped by two factors $angle and $treatment:

`z= Tracer angle treatment
60 0 S
51 0 S
56.415 15 X
56.410 15 X`

`b=Tracer angle treatment
21 0 S
15 0 S
16.415 15 X
26.410 15 X`

[image]
So far I've calculated the mean for each variable based on angle and treatment:

`aggmeanz <-aggregate(z$Tracer, list(angle=z$angle,treatment=z$treatment), FUN=mean)
aggmeanb <-aggregate(b$Tracer, list(angle=b$angle,treatment=b$treatment), FUN=mean)`

It now looks like this:
`aggmeanz
   angle treatment          x
1     0         S 0.09088021
2    30         S 0.18463353
3    60         S 0.08784315
4    80         S 0.09127198
5    90         S 0.12679296
6     0         X 2.68670392
7    15         X 0.50440692
8    30         X 0.83564470
9    60         X 0.52856956
10   80         X 0.63220093
11   90         X 1.70123025`

But when I come to plot it, I can't quite get what I'm after

```
ggplot(aggmeanz, aes(x=aggmeanz$angle,y=aggmeanz$x/aggmeanb$x, colour=treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=0.1, ymax=1.15),
                width=.2,                    
                position=position_dodge(.9))  +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

**EDIT:**

```
dput(aggmeanz)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "15", "30", "60", "80", "90"
), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(56.0841582902523, 61.2014237854156, 42.9900742785269, 
    42.4688447229277, 41.3354173870287, 45.7164231791512, 55.3943182966382, 
    55.0574951462903, 48.1575625699563, 60.5527200655174, 45.8412287451211
    )), .Names = c("time", "treatment", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(aggmeanb)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "15", "30", "60", "80", "90"
), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S", "X"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(56.26325504249, 61.751655279608, 43.1687113436753, 
    43.4147408285209, 41.9113698082799, 46.2800894420131, 55.1550995335947, 
    54.7531592595068, 47.3280215294235, 62.4629068516043, 44.2590192583692
    )), .Names = c("time", "treatment", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT 2: I calculated the standard dev as follows:

`aggstdevz <-aggregate(z$Tracer, list(angle=z$angle,treatment=z$treatment), FUN=std)
aggstdevb <-aggregate(b$Tracer, list(angle=b$angle,treatment=b$treatment), FUN=std)`

Any thoughts would be much appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: How about using `geom_boxplot`?

Comment: I'd like to plot mean(z)/mean(b) for each group. e.g. for angle 0, treatment S, find the mean std. then plot. z and b don't have the same number of observations or points, they're quite different.

Comment: Can you include a `dput` of your data?!

Comment: Could you clarify please? Do you think this is a difficult problem? Or is it something I'm not seeing?

Comment: Should be doable... However, can you add the output of `dput(aggmeanz)` to your post

Comment: Thx for the dput.... However, I think the error begins a bit before that. You have two different datasets (z and b), now you want to have mean(z)/mean/(b) at the y-axis and angle at the x-axis. What data should be displayed with the error-bars?

Comment: First join `z` and `b` into a single dataset. Then add a new column with z/b. Then use [stat_summary](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the problem in two steps:

1. create a data frame (say `data`) which contains all the information
   you would like to visualize. In this case, this seems to be the two
   factors (`angle`, `treatment`), the mean group differences (say `dif`)
   and standard errors (say `ste`).
2. visualize this information.

Step 2) will be easy. This should probably produce something very similar to your sketch.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=angle, y=dif, colour=treatment)) + 
     geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.1)) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=dif-ste, ymax=dif+ste), width=.1, position=position_dodge(0.1)) + 
     theme_bw()
```

However, at this point, you do not provide enough information to get help with Step 1. Try to include code which produces your original data (or the type of data you have) instead of copy-pasting chunks of your data output or pasting the aggregated data which lacks standard errors.

Combining your two aggregated data frames and generating random numbers for standard error produces the graph below:

```
#I imported your two aggregated data frames from your dput output.
data <- cbind(aggmeanb, aggmeanz$x, rnorm(11))
names(data) <- c("angle", "treatment", "meanz", "meanb", "ste")
data$dif <- data$meanz - data$meanb
```

[image: plot demonstration with randomly generated confidence intervals]

Comment: I think this is spot on what I was hoping for! Thank you soo much, it's great :-) One thing: I get the error message: ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead. Why does thi scome as you've defined it in geom_errorbar right?

Comment: It's a warning and not an error. It refers to the scale of the y-axis, which I did not specify. 
What I did is specifying the upper (ymax) and lower (ymin) values of the error bars.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, you'll need to join the two dataframes together. There are also some little quirks in the dput data you showed, so I've renamed some columns to make sure that they join appropriately and match what you've attempted. NOTE: You'll need name the two means differently so that they don't get merged together or cause conflicts.

```
names(aggmeanb)[names(aggmeanb) == "x"] = "mean_b"
names(aggmeanb)[names(aggmeanb) == "time"] = "angle"
names(aggmeanz)[names(aggmeanz) == "x"] = "mean_z"
names(aggmeanz)[names(aggmeanz) == "time"] = "angle"

joined_data = join(aggmeanb, aggmeanz)
joined_data$divmean = joined_data$mean_b/joined_data$mean_z

> head(joined_data)
  angle treatment   mean_b   mean_z divmean
1     0         S 56.26326 56.08416 1.003193
2    30         S 61.75166 61.20142 1.008991
3    60         S 43.16871 42.99007 1.004155
4    80         S 43.41474 42.46884 1.022273
5    90         S 41.91137 41.33542 1.013934
6     0         X 46.28009 45.71642 1.012330


ggplot(joined_data, aes(factor(angle), divmean)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

It might be that the data you've included is just a bit of your real data set, but as is there's only one data point per angle-treatment group. However, when you are using a fuller dataset, you can try something like:

```
ggplot(joined_data, aes(factor(angle), diffmean, group = treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(.~angle, scales = "free_x")
```

That will group the boxes by angle and then allow you to fill them by treatment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's really fantastic! Just to clarify, what is the boxplot showing? Are the Q1 and Q3 showing standard deviations now? And the ranges?

Comment: The boxplots will show quartiles... which seems to assuage your need to have error bars. Check ```?geom_bar``` for the argument. Once again, the second plot will look much better once you have more data. Right now it's only showing on point per category, so of course you won't see any distribution.

Comment: Ah, I just realised that the boxplots are only showing one factor ($angle) but not $treatment.  I have one mean and one stdev for each angle and each treatment. Essentially it's the second plot but with some errorbars. Is the one I drew above not possible at all?

Comment: Right, see my comment above. It impossible to draw a box plot with only one data point. Currently the data set only has one point per angle/treatment combination. Think of box plots as aggregations of points-- they show the spread of a set of points in a certain category.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm really sorry I wasn't clearer. I have all the data and all the standard deviations: aggrstdevz and aggrstdevb. I just couldn't find anywhere that the syntax of such a plot might be something like: boxplot(xdata,ydata,meandata,stdevdata)